# should free the thread object? C#

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

```
public partial class MainWindow : window
{
    private Thread t = new Thread;

    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (t != null)
        {
            if (t.IsAlive == true)
            {
                t.Abort();
                t = null; //Is this correct? should I free this before making null?
                return;
            }

            t = new Thread(send.Image);
            t.Start();    
        }
    }
}
```

The above code shows an event handler. When I press a button called 'Send' new process should be created. and when I click the same button, process should stop. Then again I will press 'Send' and the process should start again. The thread should be created in same object 't'.

Comment: Do you really want to abort the last send based on user input? Without knowing what send.Image does hard to say, but this doesn't look right. Backgroundworker worker might be a better choice. Abort should be left for extraordinary situations, it's no different to Killing a process, should only be done when there's no alternative, you should have many.

Comment: Think about using a more abstract way of usign threads, at least threadpool or more better TPL.

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of de-referencing the Thread is that you allow the GC to collect any data the Thread class holds however you permanently [stop the thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyayh29d.aspx) when you call Abort.  As the thread class does not implement IDisposable there is no way to deterministically release any unmanaged resources held by the class, we hope Abort will do that.

The Thread class is fairly light weight and unless you have many MainWindows running at the same it will probably not impact your memory consumption.  However it is good practice to be de-reference your objects if you know you will never use them again.

Answer (score 1):

It is technically ok to do so, but you would have to do it this way:

```
private Thread t; // initially null
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (t != null) 
    { 
        t.Abort(); 
        t = null;
    }
    else
    {
        t = new Thread(send.Image); 
        t.Start();     
    } 
}
```

Also, it is perhaps no good design to call `Abort`.

You might instead implement your thread method in a way that it cyclically checks for a [WaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.WaitHandle.aspx). This enables the thread to terminate in a controlled manner:

```
private Thread t; // initially null
private AutoResetEvent waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

private void btnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (t != null) 
    { 
        waitHandle.Set(); // signal thread termination
        t = null;
    }
    else
    {
        t = new Thread(ThreadMethod); 
        t.Start();     
    } 
} 

private void ThreadMethod()
{
    TimeSpan waitTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    while (!waitHandle.WaitOne(waitTime))
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: about using waitHandle, problem is, thread method 'send.Image' takes too much time. about 9 hours. I'm starting the thread by pressing 'Send' button of UI window. These many hours, my UI mainwindow should remain responsive. and I agree with 'if-else'. It should be optimized.